# How to force UIImageView of a custom cell to override table separator?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiview, uiimageview

I am having a custom cell where I add a UIImageView as a subview for the cell's contentView.

This UIImageView is placed outside the boundaries of the cell which results with image appearing underneath the table view separator as follows:

[image]

I wish that the image will override the table view separator as follows:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you can't do with tablview's separator. You first need to hide tableview's separator (i.e set seperator to none from IB or you can set to none by code also).

Take `UIView` with same width of separator and with `height = 1` or `2` if want thick separator. And put it to the end of contentview of cell.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to default separators in tableview and add a simple uiview line as a subview to your cell below your image view.